# how to modify or something similar to @model.count for count rows depending on cell value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

probably the wrong way to go about doing this but im still quite new to the MVC scene. .At the moment i have count all rows for the tables (See example below)

```
public int JobCount()
    {
        int JobCount = db.Jobs.Count();
        return JobCount;
    }
```

I basically want something similar but count the number of rows in a table if the value of that row has a status of "high" and so on

I know there is javascript as well for this but i want to be passed to the controller so that i can initialize it in the home controller for a live feed.

I've tried counting using javascript but i thought there could be an easier way.

if you need any further information let me know :)

Comment: What's your Question?

Comment: What is `db`? I'm not very good with LINQ but it looks like you could probably use that to filter out non-High values (see lucuma's answer), then just get the Count as you are. But yea the post is kind of unclear. Your title isn't a question at all and I don't really know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can typically do that by:

```
 db.Jobs.Where(x=>x.Status=="high").Count()
```

Assuming Model is a list of Jobs:

```
@Model.Where(x=>x.Status=="high").Count()
```

Comment: If it works for you and answers your question don't forget to mark it (or the best one) as the answer in order to help others.

Comment: i will :) wont allow to accept answer for 8 mins haha